# Django YearArchiveView not finding any posts for specified year

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I've just started trying out Django's class based views and the MonthArchiveView has been working great for me but when I tried using the YearArchiveView it gives me a 404 message saying:

> No post found matching the query

And I know there are posts that *should* match the query. For example, */blog/2014/* , gives me the 404 but */blog/2014/may/* does what it should

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post
from blog.views import PostMonthArchiveView, PostYearArchiveView

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    # main blog page w/ most recent 5 posts
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:5],
        template_name="blog/list.html"), name="blog"),

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        template_name="blog/post.html"), name="postdetail"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', DetailView.as_view(
        model=Post,
        template_name="blog/post.html"), name="postdetail"),

    # Example: /2012/aug/
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[-\w]+)/$',
        PostMonthArchiveView.as_view(),
        name="archive_month"),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[-\w]+)$',
        PostMonthArchiveView.as_view(),
        name="archive_month"),

    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
        PostYearArchiveView.as_view(),
        name="post_year_archive"),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})$',
        PostYearArchiveView.as_view(),
        name="post_year_archive"),
)
```

and my views

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Post
from django.views.generic.dates import MonthArchiveView, YearArchiveView

def post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {
        'post': post,
        })

class PostMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    date_field = "created"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True

class PostYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    date_field = "created"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True
```

Any help would be great, this has been causing me quite a headache and I can't find anything else on the internet to try and help troubleshoot this. Thanks!

EDIT: using Django 1.6.2

Comment: Why do you have two patterns in your urls.py pointing to the same view?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid how I had it originally I would get a 404 if the url was _/blog/some-title_ instead of _/blog/some-title/_ so I added another to account for both situations

Comment: That is bad for all sorts of reasons, and especially for SEO (since you've now split hits across two different URLs). But Django includes default functionality to redirect from /blog/some-title to /blog/some-title/ - see [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd looked closely at the error you were getting, and even better posted it in full, you would have seen that it is being caused by the DetailView, not the YearArchiveView. That's because the URL "/blog/2014/" is valid for the *detail* URL, '^(?P[-\w]+)/$', and is therefore being captured there - it never makes it to the archive one at all.

You could fix this by moving the definition for the archive view above the one for the detail, or possibly by making the detail regex more specific.

Comment: changed my url to be /blog/archive/ and put it before the DetailView one and it's working great now! Also thanks for the recommendation for APPEND_SLASH. Didn't know about that and it's working good too